# How to add onclick function for programmatically created button

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table wherein I add rows using javascript when a button is clicked. Here's my code:

```
$("#addToDisplay").click(function (event) {
    $("#tblProducts").removeClass("hide");
    var counter = 1;
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var newRow = "<tr><td>" + $("#txtProducts").val() + "</td><td>" + ("#txtQty").val()  "</td><td><input type='button' value='Remove' id='btnRemove' /></td></tr>";
    $("#tblProducts").append(newRow);
});
```

My problem is since I add the remove button per row, hence including it inside the variable newRow, how do I add an onClick event for it so that if I clicked the remove button the corresponding rows would be removed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first place a common class on your dynamic button

like `<input type='button' value='Remove' class='remove' />` and give a unique id to your input button if you want id there. you can make unique id by using counter variable, which you are using in your code.

```
$("#addToDisplay").click(function (event) {
    $("#tblProducts").removeClass("hide");
    var counter = 1;
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var newRow = "<tr><td>" + $("#txtProducts").val() + "</td><td>" + $("#txtQty").val() + "</td><td><input type='button' value='Remove' id='btnRemove"+counter+"' class='remove' /></td></tr>";
    $("#tblProducts").append(newRow);
});
```

and add the following code, it will remove the parent row of remove button.

```
 $("#tblProducts").on('click', '.remove', function(){
       $(this).closest('tr').remove();
 })
```

Or If you are generating your dynamic ids, you can change it to work with id like

```
$("#tblProducts").on('click', '[id^=btnRemove]', function(){
     $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
});
```

Comment: A quick question though, is it possible to use the id of the button instead of the class? like $("#tblProducts").on('click', '"btnRemove' + counter + '"', function() { $('#btnRemove' + counter).closest('tr').remove();

Comment: @user1597438, For this you should try this.. $("#tblProducts").on('click', '[Id^=btnRemove]', function(){  $(this).closest('tr').remove(); });

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow you correctly but what I'm trying to do now is get data from the selected row and pass it into the database so it can remove the said data from the database. Basically, what I'm trying to do now is subtract the quantity entered from the quantity on the database where the name matches the name entered on the textbox. Now, I need to revert this when the dynamic button is clicked. It should get the table data for product and quantity from the selected row and pass it to MVC.Net which would take care of the database update.

Answer (score 2):

Two options, you can register a click on the table or on a single button (row). if you have a large amount of rows, and therefor of buttons it might make sense to register the click on the table to have less listeners in the system.

If you want to programmatically register an event on any newly created item you could do the following:

```
var $myItem = $('<input type="button"/>');
$myItem.on('click', function(e) {});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach an event handler for the click.

```
$("#dynamicButton").on("click", function(e) { });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("click", "#dynamicButton", function(e) { });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give each row an ID containing the counter variable, so that each ones ID was based on the count at that point then you could easily remove by the ID of the row that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I used following code for add:

```
var tbl= document.getElementById('tgtbl'); var tblrow = tbl.insertRow(tbl.rows.length);
var cell1 = tblrow.insertCell(0); cell1.innerText = tname; cell1.textContent = tname;
var cell2 = tblrow.insertCell(1); cell2.innerText = tvalue; cell2.textContent = tvalue;
var cell3 = tblrow.insertCell(2); cell3.innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick="removerow(' + (tbl.rows.length - 1) + ')">Remove</a>';
```

and for remove (tdata was hidden field):

```
    var tbl = document.getElementById('tgtbl');
var tname = tbl.rows.item(rowindex).childNodes.item(0).innerText;
var idx = tdata.value.indexOf(tname.toLowerCase());
if (idx != -1) { tbl.deleteRow(rowindex);
  var tgd = tdata.value; tdata.value = tgd.substring(0, idx); tgd = tgd.substring(idx);
  if (tgd.indexOf(';') != -1) { tdata.value = tdata.value + tgd.substring(tgd.indexOf(';') + 1); }
for (i = 1; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
    tbl.rows.item(i).childNodes.item(2).innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick="removerow(' + i + ')">Remove</a>'; }
}
```

I know I havenot used jquery but the "remove" code will give an idea

Answer (score -1):

```
 $('#btnRemove').live ('click', function () {
       $(this).closest('tr').remove();
 });
```

Comment: Although this is an old post, it still ends up on google search results, so I thought I'd comment. Using `live` is deprecated since 1.7 and removed in 1.9 and you should use `on`.