# Selecting table data from a dynamically added row

Tags: jquery, json

This is connected to my previous question: [How to add onclick function for programmatically created button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267552/how-to-add-onclick-function-for-programmatically-created-button).

Now, I currently have a form with two textboxes, a button and a hidden table. When the button is clicked, the table is displayed and a row is added with the values of the textboxes on two columns and a remove button the third. I am now able to remove selected rows when the remove button is clicked. My new problem is how can I get the data of the first and second column so I can update the database?

I use JSON to update the database. Here's the code I currently have:

```
$("#addToDisplay").click(function (event) {
    $("#tblProducts").removeClass("hide");
    var counter = 1;
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var prod = {prodName: $("#txtProducts").val(), prodQty: $("#txtQty").val()}
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        traditional: true,
        url: "/Service/JsonUpdateProduct",
        dataType: "json",
        data: prod,
        success: function (result) {
            var newRow = "<tr><td id='rowProd" + counter + "'>" + $("#txtProducts").val() + "</td><td id='rowQty" + counter + "'>" + $("#txtQty").val() + "</td><td><input type='button' value='Remove' id='btnRemove" + counter + "' class='remove' /></td></tr>";
            $("#tblProducts").append(newRow);

            $("#tblProducts").on("click", ".remove", function () {
                $(this).closest("tr").remove();
                var rowCount = $("#tblProducts tr").length;
                var removeProd = {revertName: $("#rowProd" + counter).val(), revertQty: $("#rowQty" + counter).val()}
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    traditional: true,
                    url: "/Service/JsonRemoveProduct",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: removeProd,
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (rowCount == 1) {
                            $("#tblProducts").addClass("hide");
                        }
                    }
                });
                $("#productQty").val("");
                $("#autoCompleteText").val("");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I've been trying that code but all I get is a null value for the quantity which causes an error. So how do I exactly get the data of the selected ProductName and Quantity from a selected row?

I basically am trying to get something like this:

```
var data = { prodName: $("#selectedRowCell1")}
```

so I can pass it to the method in my class and update the database.

Also, is it possible to get the current Id of a different table and insert it to another table + 1. Something like this:

```
Select id from Details
then
Update Products set detailId = Details.id + 1
```

? I know this doesn't work as I've already tried it. So is something like this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, these should be separate click events, don't define a click event within the ajax callback. This is why you use the `on()` method. `.on()` acts as a `event delegator`. The `selector` is a `static element` bound to the document `on page load and not after`. This means, we can bind events to this parent element, and their children will have the event delegated to them if supplied as the 2nd argument.

```
 $("#addToDisplay").click(function (event) {
    //nothing to change here, omitted for length
 });
```

Here, the issue is how to get `productData`. By your definition, product data are the two previous columns in the row when the `.remove` class element is clicked. Let's do it.

```
$("#tblProducts").on("click", ".remove", function() {
    //when you do the following, you remove the entire row we need
    //lets not do that yet.
    //$(this).closest("tr").remove();

    var $this = $(this); //cachable -- save some performance, reference success

    var col1 = $this.closest('tr').find('#rowProd').text(), // first column
        col2 = $this.closest('tr').find('#rowQty').text(), //second column
        productData = { 'product' : col1, 'quantity' : col2};

    //now productData is properly populated with the values we need.

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        traditional: true,
        url: "/Service/JsonRemoveProduct",
        dataType: "json",
        data: productData,
        success: function(result) {

            //ajax successful, NOW we'll remove the row.      
            $this.closest("tr").remove();

            if ($this.find('tr').length;) {
                $("#tblProducts").addClass("hide");
            }
        }
    });
    $("#txtQty").val("");
    $("#txtProducts").val("");
});​
```

Comment: Oohhh. So I have to pass the data first and only remove the row when the ajax is successful. Thank you so much!

Comment: Quick question, this worked like a charm although the code inside the success function doesn't work. $(this).closest("tr").remove(); does not remove the row and the if statement stopped working as well. If I take $(this).closest("tr").remove(); out of the success function, it works but the if statement doesn't regardless of where it is. I triple checked and when it reaches the success function, it goes inside said function but does not execute either one. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @user1597438 Yes. It's `$this` not `$(this)` as you lose the scope of `$(this)` when inside an ajax handler, that's why I defined it as a cached variable outside of ajax, so within we could still reference it. Remove the parenthesis on that one. Also, let's try `rowCount = $this.find('tr').length;` and see if that helps.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I'll try that out and update you.

Comment: removing the parenthesis worked. For the other one it didn't do anything at all. I tried checking the value of rowCount and it says 2 so it doesn't execute the if statement even though there's only 1 row left.

Comment: Ah, good description. There's the issue. We need to calculate the row length `after` removing the row. Simply do `if($this.find('tr').length == 1)`. Don't even make a variable.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help and suggestions! if($this.find('tr').length == 1) didn't exactly do it so I tried if($('#tblProducts tr').length == 1) and it did the trick. Thanks again.